# Есть ли разница в употреблении "только" и "лишь"?

Tags: выбор-слов, синонимы

Есть ли разница? Когда лучше употребить "только", а когда лучше "лишь"?

1. Сдать зачёт можно **лишь** с 10:00 и до 14:45. / Сдать зачёт можно **только** с 10:00 и до 14:45.
2. Магазин работает **лишь** до восьми вечера. / Магазин работает **только** до восьми вечера.
3. Антон пробежал **лишь** пять километров. / Антон пробежал **только** пять километров.
4. Он вышел погулять **лишь** на пятнадцать минут. / Он вышел погулять **только** на пятнадцать минут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Частицы **только** и ***лишь*** во многом синонимичны, но область применения ***только*** шире. С учетом толкового словаря и просто на слух я так **различаю** эти слова.

В приведенных примерах частица ***только*** относится к определенному числовому интервалу и используется, если нужно обозначить его **ограниченность**. Это **нейтральный** стиль, сообщение **информационного** характера.

Частица ***лишь*** подчеркивает исключительность указанного временного отрезка и по контексту может иметь дополнительную **коннотацию.** Стиль ближе **к разговорному**.

Примеры **дополнительной коннотации**

*Сдать зачёт можно **лишь с 10:00 и до 14:45**. (И не надо приходить раньше или позже*.) Разговорный стиль.

*Магазин работает **лишь до восьми вечера**. Ну и магазин!*

*Антон пробежал **лишь пять километров**. Больше не осилил, а говорил, что десять пробежит.*

*Он вышел погулять **лишь на пятнадцать минут**. Не думал, что его отсутствие заметят.*

**Большой толковый словарь русского языка**

**ЛИШЬ**. I. частица. Подчёркивает **исключительность, единственность кого-, чего-л., какого-л. явления, процесса и т.п.; только, исключительно, единственно.** В саду л. ветер нарушал тишину. Л. кое-где на ночном небе видны звёзды. Он ничего не делает, л. спит да ест. // (в сочет. с частицей бы или с частицами бы, только, лишь бы, лишь только бы). Усиливает выражение какого-л. желания. Л. бы уехать сегодня. Л. только бы закончить школу. / (в сочет. с частицами: только, всего, всего-навсего, разве). В поле остались л. только копны сена.

**ТОЛЬКО.** I. частица. 1.**Не более как, всего лишь**. Вещь стоит т. рубль. Ей т. пять лет. Ходит т. в кино. Это т. начало. Танцевала т. два танца. Всего т. год жил с женой. Ещё т. двенадцать часов! Т. его и видели (разг.; не успел появиться, как уже исчез). // Не ранее чем. Вернулся т. под утро. Уедет т. вечером. 2. **Единственно, исключительно.** Говорил т. о любви. Стремится т. к победе. Не любит т. вранья. Т. в деревне и отдыхаю. Люблю т. тебя. Не купил лишь т. из жадности. 3. Употр. **после местоимений, наречий, союзов** для усиления, подчёркивания. Зачем т. я сюда приехала. Кому т. не рассказывал. Где т. не бывал. 4. Придаёт выражению значение угрозы, предостережения; посмей, попробуй. Т. тронь! Т. проиграй! Т. ослушайся!

Answer (score 0):

**ЛИШЬ** - что-то выходящее за пределы основы или количества, излишек, часто малая часть чего-то, незначительная, неосновная. Либо это указание на ложный информативный послыл всего предложения, заблуждение, ввиду его частичности по отношению к основе.

**ТОЛЬКО** - это от скорее всего от греческого слова τελικός - край, конечный, финал. То есть указывает на границы применимости или эффект от воздействия чего-то, и тп., причём основной эффект, а не дополнительный при слове "лишь". Частица чего-то имеющее ключевое значение.

Почему произошла семантическая синонимия этих слов? Дело в том, что изначально они употреблялись в связке - *только лишь*, *лишь только*. То есть указывается некий эффект от малой части чего-то, который противоречил эффекту основы.

Но вот для примера, фраза где лишь не заменима на только:

> ... Зеленые луга, разными цветами распещренные поля, густые и тихие дубравы, где поселянина ни зной солнечный, ни жестокость ветров беспокоить не может, не могут ему быть уютным местом, блеяние невинных овец слуху его противно, и чистое млеко, нежнейшая всех пастухов и пастушек пища, **лишь** возмутит желудок его. Куда ни обратится, везде находит уныние.  Ф. А. Эмин. Письма Эрнеста и Доравры (Отрывки) (1766)

Тут *лишь* - имеет оттенок противоречия, чего-то маловажного, не дающего основному жизнерадостному описанию преодолеть "его уныние", частица нарушающая гармонию При этом вся часть до "лишь" имеет попытку превзойти уныние некой жизнерадостностью. но вот это лишь, хоть и малая, всё портит и низводит предыдущие красивости на нет перед настроением "уныния".

А если бы на этом есть было *только* - тогда это было бы наоборот утверждение, что среди всего этого прекрасного пейзажа, некий пессимист нашёл к чему придраться  - к молоку вызвавшему у него расстройство желудка. И акцент был бы не на унынии, а на жизнерадостном описании. Последующей же переход к описанию уныния смотрелся бы неуместно. Поэтому тут *лишь* на *только* не заменяемо.

Поэтому **ЛИШЬ** *несёт в себе эмоциональный оттенок очарования или разочарования через противоречие*, в то время как **ТОЛЬКО** - *утверждение, пусть и малого, но без особой негативной оценки*.

Ещё пример про утверждение-отрицание:

> Разумея, что труд и убыток будет напрасной, послал **только** в Сибирь пять человек, да в Казанскую, Синбирскую и Вятскую трех. Татищев.

То есть Татищев пишет, что "подумав, он поступил расчетливо". Однако если бы тут вместо "только" было бы употреблено "лишь", то фраза могла бы иметь оттенок осуждения и вряд ли бы перед лишь стояло "разумея". Скорее было бы что-то вроде: "не разумея, что труд и убыток будет прибыльный, послал лишь в 5 человек в Сибирь".

Также **ТОЛЬКО** заменимо на **НО**, а **ЛИШЬ - нет**.

> Сей армянин, у кого зеленой купил, вы, чаю, знаете — Назарет Мануков, которой сказывает, много весчей Левашову покупал и, может, он скоро сам в Москву поедет, только великой плут и весьма на обманы хитер. Татищев.

Вот тут, ТОЛЬКО вполне заменима на НО или "но, имей ввиду, что он". То есть: армянин может быть отправлен за покупками, но стоит учесть, что он плут и может обмануть. Лишь тут было бы неуместно, потому что отрицало бы вообще возможность покупки армянином товара и возможность сотрудничества с ним: армянин, у которого купили чай, лишь плут, поэтому не стоит ему доверять хоть что-то.

Comment: Откуда берутся эмоции у частицы "лишь"?  Магазин работает лишь до восьми вечера.  Можно считать, что он все время закрыт (ирония), за небольшим исключением.

Comment: @Sharon язык - это система понятий, лишь - это то, что выходит за рамки понятия, то есть противоречие, ложный посыл и тп, поэтому эмоциональность. Понятия - это слова адресованные рациональной сфере, а не эмоциональной, а антипонятия, существующие через семантику, отсылки на другое, либо на негативные понятия вроде "ложь" имеют эмоциональную оценку, а и не нацелены на утверждение.

Comment: Магазин работает лишь до восьми вечера! - а я хотел купить, но увы, не куплю... Магазин работает только до восьми вечера, если я хочу купить что-то, то нужно поторопиться.

Comment: Меня этимология интересует: что тут у вас лишнего или чего вы лишились?  С толикой ясно, а с лишь не очень.

Comment: @Sharon лишь, это скорее всего какая-то форма частицы "ли", которая в свою очередь, имеет указание на отрицание чего-то, но не прямое, а косвенное. То ли кот - не совсем кот, не кот, но не совсем "не кот". То есть только - сближается с местоимением, относящимся к утвержденную во фразе. А лишь - не так, лишь отрицает то, что в фразе и дает некий косвенный референс на отличие, причину отрицания. Но вот если взять фразу которую я привёл, про молоко, то если оставить одно предложение, то будет не ясно, почему "лишь", потому что информация про референс лишь содержится за границами предложения.

Comment: Кот ли? - Нет, не кот, а что-то другое. - референс не на кота, а ещё на что-то. А с только всё проще, только даёт прибавку к уже утверждённому: Была ночь, только водитель не спал - все спали, но был также тот, что не спал - всего всех было: все спящие и один не спящий. Также слова ко+ль и ес(ть)+ли скорее всего тоже содержат этот корень.

Comment: Возможно, ещё предположение, что суффикс прошедшего времени, тоже связан с ЛИ, потому что даёт референт не на утверждение того, что сейчас, на на отсылку к прошедшему.

Comment: Возможно, ещё предположение, что суффикс прошедшего времени, тоже связан с Л', потому что даёт референт не на утверждение того, что сейчас, на на отсылку к прошедшему. И кстати, существительные приобретающие определённое свойство тоже образуются с помощью этого суффикса, то есть связанные с глаголом, образом действия, а не с собственно предметом, референс на функцию, а не на себя. Кадило - кадит, вышибала - вышибает, метла - метёт. То есть для чего-то ещё, намного сильнее чувствуется референс функциональности, чем в других словах.

Comment: Например, метель - метёт, а снегопад - не снегопадает, а сокращение от снег и падает, а сам снег, не ясно, что делает - снег это снег). Бредово ли?)